# Outlook.com / Hotmail / Microsoft-based email users not receiving *most* mail

Tags: php, email, outlook

On a site that I'm developing users can send messages to each-other through a basic mailing form (which we require for privacy reasons), and it works great - unless you use Microsoft-based email services. Users of these services (outlook/live/hotmail) will only receive about 1 in 10 messages. Any other email provider works without issues.

This really throws me off because I've seen an identical message get sent twice, failing the first time and passing the second (not even getting sent to junk). MS users had no issues in the first month the site was up, either.

On the client-side we tried minimizing junkmail settings and specifically setting our emails to be 'trusted' (granted, even if these work I would be unsatisfied)

On our side we tried adding SPF records, making sure our sent address is our noreply address, setting the message to HTML-only, then setting the message to plaintext-only (where it currently remains). We're on Godaddy, and speaking to their reps there's no issues on the hosting-end, and I figure if MS was blocking by the source there'd be a slew of reports.

Are there any known idiosyncratic behaviours MS has when it comes to email, where they don't junk messages but outright delete *most* of them?